# missing a using directive or an assembly reference? ASP.NET WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

i have three project in one project one is for database layer and second one is WCF and the third one is the Main site consuming these two projects so i am getting error while debugging it as

```
Error   203 'CIService.CIServiceClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetInventoryProjectDetailCompleted' and no extension method 'GetInventoryProjectDetailCompleted' accepting a first argument of type 'CIService.CIServiceClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\ProjectDetails.aspx.cs   30  27  G:\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\
```

on the following line of code,

```
CIService.CIServiceClient svcClient = new CIService.CIServiceClient();
                svcClient.GetInventoryProjectDetailCompleted += new EventHandler<CIService.GetInventoryProjectDetailCompletedEventArgs>(svcClient_GetInventoryProjectDetailCompleted);
                svcClient.GetInventoryProjectDetailAsync(consultantId, projectId);
```

this code is from main site where it is using WCF service method "GetInventoryProjectDetailCompleted" i have added WCF refrence too in main site on checking it on net i got solution to add reference in web.config file as shown,

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From this code:

```
 svcClient.GetInventoryProjectDetailCompleted += new EventHandler<CIService.GetInventoryProjectDetailCompletedEventArgs>(svcClient_GetInventoryProjectDetailCompleted);
```

it seems that `GetInventoryProjectDetailCompleted` is not method but event, isn't it?

May be you'll find this example of async call usefull:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91528/How-to-Call-WCF-Services-Synchronously-and-Asynchr

Comment: But before some time my this application is working fine but after i did some work suddenly it gave me this error ???

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help you

```
Line 10:          var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
Line 11: 
Line 12:          var txtPurchaseDate = '<%=txtPurchaseDate.ClientId %>';
Line 13: 
Line 14:          $('#' + txtPurchaseDate).datepicker({
```